# Traveling to Brazil on different passports

Tags: passports, brazil

I am a new US citizen and need to use my US passport to travel to Brazil since I need to show proof of residency and I no longer have my green card that goes with my Cyprus passport.
However, I can enter Brazil visa-free with my Cyprus passport and would like to be able to do that rather than getting a visa on my US passport.

My question: Can I depart the US with my US passport and enter Brazil with my Cyprus passport? Or, will the US airline agents demand to see a visa if I'm using the US passport? Will they be OK if I tell them I'm using the Cyprus passport to enter Brazil?

I'd appreciate your help in figuring this out.
Thanks much!
Stephan

Answer (score 1):

You can enter/leave the US on your American passport and enter/leave Brazil on your Cyprian passport.  As long as you're entering and leaving a given country on the passport of the local country (if you have one) or the same passport (if you don't have a local one) you should be fine.

In general airlines will not [check](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/36027/airline-compensation-for-failure-to-check-visa-eligibility) [your visas](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/39139/do-airlines-have-to-check-the-visa-status-before-selling-a-ticket) for you (one exception I have found is Porter Airlines from Toronto to the US, presumably because they found the cost of repatriating people who didn't sign up for ESTA exorbitant).

Comment: Typically, when it's the airline's responsibility to fly you back if you're found to not have valid papers on arrival, the airline *will* check your credentials.